# How to display the picture of the current user in a TWIG model?

Tags: templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I make a TWIG template for the home page of my Drupal 8 site.

```
page--front.html.twig
```

I want to display on this page the picture of the current user.

How to display the picture of the current user in a TWIG model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get user image:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

    if (!$user->user_picture->isEmpty()) {
      $displayImg = file_create_url($user->user_picture->entity->getFileUri());
    }else{
      $displayImg = '';    
    }
```

Then pass it as variable to twig, check if it's empty or not and depending on that print inside some img tag.

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-09-28/drupal-8-how-can-i-get-the-profile-picture-of-a-user

**Update:**

To get image style url you could do something like:

```
$style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('thumbnail');
$url = $style->buildUrl($displayImg);
```

Based on: https://www.webomelette.com/how-render-your-images-image-styles-drupal-8

And you should assign twig variable from your home page controller.

Comment: Thanks, is a custom module or in the .theme file ? Is there another method for doing this ? For example I can get the username with `{{ user.displayname }}` and the ID with `{{ user.id }}` directly in TWIG years. I would like to display the picture of the user with a style.

Comment: Updated my answer on how to get image style url. Sorry, I don't know better solution for this even it does sound logical what you expected.

Comment: How should I do ? must you put this code in .theme or in a custom module?